# Cancelar subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, observer-pattern, rxjs

Eu estou realizando uma chamada para API que me retorna uma lista de um obj qualquer quando eu clico em um button. Ou seja se eu clico duas vezes em sequência, a API me retorna a mesma lista em sequência também.

Minha dúvida é, como eu faço para se eu clicar duas vezes rápido em sequência, eu cancelar a primeira request e pegar apenas o valor do ultimo click. Eu tentei utilizar o Switmap, porém não tive sucesso. Segue o código abaixo...

```
getBookingByUserAndStatus(): void
{
        this.loading = true;
        const getByUserAndStatus = this._bookingsService.getByUserAndStatus(this.user._id, this.statusSelect).subscribe(resp => 
        {
            console.log(resp);
            this.loading = false;
            this._foverNotificationService.notify('Lista carregada', SnackbarStatusEnum.success);
        },
        error =>
        {
            this.loading = false;
            this._foverNotificationService.notify(error, SnackbarStatusEnum.error);
        },
        () => getByUserAndStatus.unsubscribe());
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu clico 2 vezes em sequência no botão teste, eu recebo 2 vezes em sequência a resposta da API como mostra a notificação..

Desde já agradeço....

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar o **[take(1)](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take)**.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
this._bookingsService.getByUserAndStatus(this.user._id, this.statusSelect)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(resp => ... );
```

Comment: Também não funcionou, eu editei minha pergunta, colocando visualmente o que acontece!!

Comment: Tenta sem o `getByUserAndStatus.unsubscribe()`.

Answer (score -2):

Sei que já se passou um tempo desde a pergunta mas mesmo assim vou tentar consolidar uma resposta tendo em vista que essa pode ser a dúvida de outros devs futuramente.

Conforme foi perguntado, na minha resposta eu vou seguir a linha de sempre considerar apenas a requisição ativada pelo click mais recente num botão, ou seja, desconsiderar requisições dos clicks anteriores.

Minha abordagem usa o [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) e tentei ser bem didático no exemplo de forma que pode ser verificado no console do navegador o que está ocorrendo por baixo do capô através dos `console.log()`. Também comentei o código de forma que possa ser mais facilmente compreendido e aplicado.

Tive o cuidado de adicionar no código completo uma abordagem para fazer o "unsubscribe", mas como não é o foco da pergunta, não passarei por isso.

### Explicando passo-a-passo

Ao invés de executar a ação do click diretamente no método do binding, a estratégia é a cada click lançar emissões num `Subject`.

```
  // Faça o binding do botão para este método aqui
  executarAcao() {
    (...)
    this.clickBotaoSubject$.next();
  }
```

Use o `switchMap` para considerar apenas a emissão mais recente do `clickBotaoSubject$`, ou seja, considerar apenas o último click no botão para então efetuar um novo request:

```
  observaApenasClickMaisRecente$ = this.clickBotaoSubject$.asObservable().pipe(
    (...)
    // Troque o `requestSimulado$` pelo seu request da API
    switchMap((_) => this.requestSimulado$)
  );
```

Então, inscreva-se no `observaApenasClickMaisRecente$` para executar as ações necessárias da sua aplicação. Aqui estou usando o método `construtor` para a inscrição, mas poderia ser no `ngOnInit` ou outro que método que execute apenas uma vez ao iniciar o componente:

```
constructor() {
    this.observaApenasClickMaisRecente$.subscribe({
      next: (resposta) => {
        // só o último click chegará aqui
        console.log(resposta.message);
      },
      error: (_err: any) => {
        // trata o erro
      },
      complete: () => {
        // executa alguma coisa, se for o caso
        console.log('Completou');
      },
    });
  }
```

### Exemplo de saídas de log no console

#### Click único

```
-----------------------------
Clicou no botão Executar Ação
Contador do click atual é 1
Retorno da API para o click 1  <-- como foi um click sozinho, retornou resultado
```

### 3 clicks rápidos seguidos

```
-----------------------------
Clicou no botão Executar Ação
Contador do click atual é 2
-----------------------------
Clicou no botão Executar Ação
Contador do click atual é 3
-----------------------------
Clicou no botão Executar Ação
Contador do click atual é 4
Retorno da API para o click 4     <-- ignorou os clicks 2 e 3, então retorna a última request do click 4
```

### Código completo

*typescript*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teste',
  templateUrl: './teste.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teste.component.css'],
})
export class TesteComponent implements OnDestroy {
  // Para verificação do funcionamento
  // fins didáticos
  contador = 0;

  // usado para fazer "unsubscribe"
  untilDestroyNotify$ = new Subject<void>();

  // Subject emitirá "eventos" de click no botão
  clickBotaoSubject$ = new Subject<void>();

  // Simula uma requisição a uma API
  // que retorna após 2 segundos
  requestSimulado$ = defer(() =>
    of({ message: `Retorno da API para o click ${this.contador}` }).pipe(
      delay(2000)
    )
  );

  // Observable que emitirá apenas a última requisição
  observaApenasClickMaisRecente$ = this.clickBotaoSubject$.asObservable().pipe(
    // esse `tap` serve apenas para demonstração
    tap({
      next: () => {
        this.contador++;
        console.log(`Contador do click atual é ${this.contador}`);
      },
    }),

    // O switchMap irá desconsiderar as emissões dos clicks anteriores
    // e considerar apenas a emissão do click mais recente...
    // Troque o `requestSimulado$` pelo seu request da API
    switchMap((_) => this.requestSimulado$),
    takeUntil(this.untilDestroyNotify$)
  );

  constructor() {
    this.observaApenasClickMaisRecente$.subscribe({
      next: (resposta) => {
        // só o último click chegará aqui
        console.log(resposta.message);
      },
      error: (_err: any) => {
        // trata o erro
      },
      complete: () => {
        // executa alguma coisa, se for o caso
        console.log('Completou');
      },
    });
  }

  // Faça o binding do click do botão para este método aqui
  executarAcao() {
    console.log('-----------------------------');
    console.log('Clicou no botão Executar Ação');

    // Cada click no botão gera uma emissão de click
    // para ser tratada pelo `observaApenasClickMaisRecente`
    this.clickBotaoSubject$.next();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.untilDestroyNotify$.next();
    this.untilDestroyNotify$.complete();
  }
}
```

*html*

```
<button (click)="executarAcao()">Executar Ação</button>
```

### Aviso

Com essa abordagem o frontend só receberá a resposta da última requisição à API, mas isso não significa que a API não receberá e processará todas as requisições anteriores, e dessa forma, podendo ocasionar inconsistências na sua aplicação... É bom ficar de olho.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Alguém poderia esclarecer o motivo dos down votes para que eu possa evoluir minha resposta à contento? Vejo que participar do StackOverflow em Português têm sido mais dificultado do que o StackOverflow principal...